# jest-dynalite with @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb v3 - Error [ReadError]: Database is not open

Tags: node.js, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb, jest-dynalite

I'm trying to migrate from aws-sdk v2 to v3. I use jest-dynalite version `3.6.1`. Works great with v2. But as I am migrating to v3, I get the following error:

```
Error [ReadError]: Database is not open
```

I tried two variations of code:

```
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, GetCommand, QueryCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb');
const { DynamoDBClient } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');

const dynamodb = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(new DynamoDBClient({"sslEnabled":true,"apiVersion":"latest","region":"local","endpoint":"http://localhost:8071"}));
```

and also the following:

```
const { GetCommand, QueryCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb');
const { DynamoDBClient } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');

const dynamodb = new DynamoDBClient({"sslEnabled":true,"apiVersion":"latest","region":"local","endpoint":"http://localhost:8071"});
```

And my jest-dynalite-config:

```
module.exports = {
    tables: [...some-table-data...],
    basePort: 8070
};
```

Not sure what is going on. Is my `endpoint` wrong ? When I run the test case, this is the error:

```
/Users/....../node_modules/dynalite/index.js:263
      if (err) throw err
               ^
Error [ReadError]: Database is not open
    at /Users/....../node_modules/levelup/lib/levelup.js:198:15
    at /Users/....../node_modules/encoding-down/index.js:75:21
```

Comment: Were you able to start DynamoDB Local?

Comment: @LeeHannigan, nope. I think jest-dynalite spawns a local DB at the port specified in the jest-dynalite-config, so I dont need to run any instance locally when the tests are running.. should be handled by jest-dynalite itself.

Comment: From a DynamoDB perspective this exception is usually thrown when connecting to the wrong port or when Local isn't running, or commonly there is permission errors. I don't know anything about Dynalite